How to know weight limit of TV mount?
Is it possible to determine the weight and size limit of a TV wall mount? The place I'm in comes with a TV mount on the wall, but no discernable brand or model markings.
It's about 32.25 in wide X 9.5in tall.



Weigh your TV or look up its specs. Using a fish scale (additive) or bathroom scale (deductive), apply that much weight. Note how much things move and creak. Make a judgement call.
The fact is that mounts rarely fail. They just perform poorly if they're flexing or tilting too much. What fails is the installation. Be sure it's secured properly to framing or suitable anchors.

I have this mount. It's a Monoprice mount claimed to handle "up to 175 lbs".
It's been solid. I had it for about 10 yrs and just mounted a 65" to it. You'll need the two TV VESA brackets.
I also recommend adding some lubricant to the joints, as the arms get stiff after a while.

@isherwood, i dont see it as a product review. The user has identified the bracket and posted a link to it. So plusding it.

@RohitGupta, links are not answers on SE networks. Answers must include relevant information here. This is standard. The only content in this answer is a product review and a lubrication recommendation. That doesn't address the question. See [answer] for a refresher.

I took the liberty of adding that information (and fixing numerous run-on sentences). Now it addresses the question.

@user229752 thanks! Super sleuth to the rescue. I upvoted your answer, but I'm going to keep the other answer as the accepted one since the original question was about how to determine weight limit.

I see two lag screws. There are hopefully a couple more hidden from the camera's view.  Take steps to ensure you have wood studs, and those screws are all firmly screwed to them.
The plastic low-voltage port is probably covering a hole large enough for you to look inside the wall and see directly a stud aligned with the left screw.  You can then measure the separation (hopefully 16 or 24 inches) and/or rotate or remove the other ones to check them.
If the bracket is securely mounted to studs, it looks strong enough to hold any modern TV up to about 80 inches.  If you have some 300lb plasma monster from the 00s, it would probably cost you less to by a great new TV than a better bracket.  If you have a 100-inch TV, regardless of its weight you should buy the recommended mount for it.
Did the previous occupant leave you the pair of brackets that mount on the TV?   Those are usually proprietary to the mount.  You can't buy them separately and shouldn't rely on random ones fitting this bracket.   If you have ones on your TV that seem to fit, imagine someone was paying you to make them fall off the bracket and try your best to do it.
